# What is the geometric interpretation of the action of a degenerate real skew-symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-transformations, rotations, isometry, skew-mapping

As discussed in [What is the geometrical action of a skew-symmetric matrix on an arbitrary vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142241/what-is-the-geometrical-action-of-a-skew-symmetric-matrix-on-an-arbitrary-vector), an arbitrary real skew-symmetric matrix can be brought into the block diagonal form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix}0 & \lambda_1\\ -\lambda_1 & 0\end{matrix} &  0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \begin{matrix}0 & \lambda_2\\ -\lambda_2 & 0\end{matrix} &  & 0 \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \begin{matrix}0 & \lambda_r\\ -\lambda_r & 0\end{matrix} \\
& & & & \begin{matrix}0 \\ & \ddots \\ & & 0 \end{matrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$
via a real orthonormal similarity transformation. This demonstrates that the operator's geometric action is to annihilate components of vectors in certain directions and dilate and rotate other components by $\pi/2$ in the $x^i-x^{i+1}$ planes in other directions.

But I'm curious what happens in the "degenerate" case. Without significant loss of generality, let's consider the simplest case where we have a single pair of degenerate blocks; i.e. the operator $A$ is orthonormally similar to 
$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\
-\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda \\
0 & 0 & -\lambda & 0
\end{matrix} \right].$$

Again without significant loss of generality, we can further simplify by rescaling the operator by $1/\lambda$ to get that $A$ is (up to an overall constant) orthonormally similar to 
$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{matrix} \right].$$

Is there a simple geometric characterization of the set of such operators $A$ (beyond the generic situation described above)?

Roughly speaking, I'm curious about the geometric symmetry group of such an operator. For example: based on my experience with diagonalizable matrices, I suspect that such a "degenerate" operator may be secretly isotropic (or at least have a higher degree of geometric symmetry than the generic antisymmetric case). Is this the case, or does there exist a unique pair of orthogonal planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ about which these rotations occur? If it is isotropic, is there a simpler/more geometrically intuitive description of its action, which manifestly demonstrates the isotropy?